# Order of references in reference list

Tags: bibtex

My minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}

Here I refer to~\cite{Smaili:2011aa} and here I refer to~\cite{Edwards:2010aa}.


This is a table where I mention all my references:

\begin{table}[!htb]
    \begin{tabular}{lll}
    Reference 1 & Edwards &  \cite{Edwards:2010aa} \\
    Reference 2 & Smaili &  \cite{Smaili:2011aa} \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{biblio}

\end{document}
```

And the corresponding bib file:

```
@conference{Smaili:2011aa,
    Author = {Smaili, Hafid and Breeman, Jan and Lombaerts, Thomas and Stroosma, Olaf},
    Booktitle = {4th European Conference for Aerospace Sciences},
    Title = {{A} {B}enchmark for {F}ault {T}olerant {F}light {C}ontrol {E}valuation},
    Year = {2011}}

@book{Edwards:2010aa,
    Author = {Christopher Edwards and Thomas Lombaerts and Hafid Smaili},
    Publisher = {Springer},
    Title = {{F}ault {T}olerant {F}light {C}ontrol: {A} {B}enchmark {C}hallenge},
    Year = {2010}}
```

The result is:

[image]

I want the order of my references to depend on the appearance within my *table* (instead of my complete report). In this table I list all my references including some information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `\nocite{}` commands in the table order at the start of the document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@conference{Smaili:2011aa,
    Author = {Smaili, Hafid and Breeman, Jan and Lombaerts, Thomas and Stroosma, Olaf},
    Booktitle = {4th European Conference for Aerospace Sciences},
    Title = {{A} {B}enchmark for {F}ault {T}olerant {F}light {C}ontrol {E}valuation},
    Year = {2011}}

@book{Edwards:2010aa,
    Author = {Christopher Edwards and Thomas Lombaerts and Hafid Smaili},
    Publisher = {Springer},
    Title = {{F}ault {T}olerant {F}light {C}ontrol: {A} {B}enchmark {C}hallenge},
    Year = {2010}}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
\nocite{Edwards:2010aa}
\nocite{Smaili:2011aa}

Here I refer to~\cite{Smaili:2011aa} and here I refer to~\cite{Edwards:2010aa}.


This is a table where I mention all my references:

\begin{table}[!htb]
    \begin{tabular}{lll}
    Reference 1 & Edwards &  \cite{Edwards:2010aa} \\
    Reference 2 & Smaili &  \cite{Smaili:2011aa} \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]